# How does the colour of an object affect its heat absorption/radiation properties?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

Black objects are better heat absorber and emitter, so if I paint something black, I am changing its absorption/radiation properties. How do you explain this? (I understand an object looks black to our eyes because it absorbs all spectrums of visible light, I would like to know how this works in microscopic scale).

Answer (score 1):

Imagine an object which looks bright white. It appears white because it is reflecting most of the light that strikes it- all colors of light equally- and absorbing almost none.

An object that looks dark black is absorbing equally all colors of light that strike it, and reflecting very little.

An object that looks red, for example, is reflecting the red wavelengths and absorbing all other colors- so the light coming from it that hits your eye will be red, even though the light that originally struck it was white (because it contained all the colors).

On the molecular or atomic scale, the electrons that form the outermost orbital cloud surrounding the nucleus exhibit the ability to preferentially absorb certain frequencies (colors) of light while ignoring other colors. So a chemical compound that looks red has electron orbital levels which readily absorb all colors of light except those it mostly ignores- in this case, red light.